# Discord Bot Can't Get Channel by Name

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have been making a discord bot and wanted to make it send a message to a specific "Welcome" channel. Unfortunately, I have been unable to do so. I tried this.

```
const welcomeChannel = bot.channels.get("name", "welcome")
welcomeChannel.sendMessage("Welcome\n"+member.user.username);
```

However in this "welcomeChannel is undefined".

Edit:

I tried using

```
const welcomeChannel = bot.channels.get("id", "18NUMBERIDHERE")
welcomeChannel.sendMessage("Welcome\n"+member.user.username);
```

but this is still undefined, strangely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot can't find channel by name or id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463163/discord-bot-cant-find-channel-by-name-or-id)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should use the channnel id instead of it's name.

How to get the channel id of a channel:

1. Open up your Discord Settings
2. Go to `Advanced`
3. Tick `Developer Mode` (And close the Discord settings)
4. Right click on your desired channel
5. Now there's an option `Copy ID` to copy the channel id

Also checkout the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=setChannelPositions) for (channel) collections

---

Furthermore your approach won't work because `.get` wants a channel id (see the linked documentation above). In case you **REALLY** want to get an channel by its name, use `.find` instead for that.
This is however a really bad idea in case your bot runs on more than one server since channel names can now occur multiple times.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work either. I edited in the new code.

Comment: @FishProHD it's `bot.channels.get("18NUMBERIDHERE")`, not `bot.channels.get("id", "18NUMBERIDHERE")`

Comment: I'm gonna give you the bounty tomorrow. I like your answer and believe you deserve the bounty because of the detailed yet simple steps you have given. (also, kind of irrelevant, i want the badge that comes with it)

Comment: @TyQ. I currently don't have time anymore to post detailed answers on SO, so I highly appriciate the bounty! Thanks stranger

Comment: This question has been answered here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463163/discord-bot-cant-find-channel-by-name-or-id?rq=1.
Not to mention at the time this was asked, the docs had changed, .get or .find, does not work anymore for getting channels, you would have to use the fetch method, as mentioned on the second answer of the link I posted. Further more the answer here does not really answer the question, and I am confused as to why he would need to worry about setting channel positions, when he is asking why he can't get the channel by name or id.

Comment: How to get the channel id of a channel? I landed here because of it, but the "Tick Developer Mode" in this answer is no longer there, or I wasn't able to find it. Oh, I got it. Settings -> Advanced -> Developer Mode. I'll edit the answer directly.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use

```
bot.channels.find("name","welcome").send("Welcome!")
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot with the same error, and that's how I fixed it. I used client as my Client().

```
client.channels.cache.get("18NUMBERIDHERE").send("Welcome!");
```

Comment: What does `cache.get` return for channels not yet cached ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error could come from the fact that you're using `bot.channels.get()`, which isn't the best idea, because discord.js isn't very friendly when it comes to using `.send()` on multiple items.

Instead, try to use `member.guild.channels.find("name", "channel").send();`, if possible. If this is in the `client.on("message")`, then simply use `message.member.channels.find("name", "channel").send();`

Sidenote: My memory is mixed up, so if that doesn't work, try `.get()` instead of `find`.