# Sending welcome messages when someone joins the server using discord.js

Tags: discord.js, member

I am using Visual Studio Code with node.js and discord.js. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759835/welcome-message-when-joining-discord-server-using-discord-js) previous thread and tried the code `client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => { member.guild.channels.get('[the channel id]').send("Welcome");  });` but when people join it's not sending the message.

Comment: `cache.get()` for v12 and onward

Comment: @Elitezen huh? I have discord.js@12.5.3

Comment: Yes, so use `member.guild.channels.cache.get`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issues you could try

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
     const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === 'id-of-the-channel-here');
     welcomeChannel.send(`Hello there ${member}`);
}
```

To make this work though, make sure you have enabled **Privileged Gateway Intents** on https://discord.com/developers/applications

[image]

Comment: While it's not a big issue, it's better to use `.get()` over `.find()` for channel id's

Comment: I have gotten used to using `.find()` @Elitezen