# Discord Bot can't find channel by name or id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot with DiscordJS

I want to fetch a specific channel :

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

    var bot = new Discord.Client();
    var myToken = 'NDQ2OTQ1...................................................';

    var channelFind = bot.channels.find("id","XXXXXXXXXXX"); // null
    var channelGet = bot.channels.get("id","XXXXXXXXXXX"); // undefined
```

Whenever I run my bot, it returns `null` with `find` and `undefined` with `get`.
I also tried to find my channel by name

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you've placed your "find" line within an event listener.
For example, let's say you wanted to find the specific channel when the bot connects successfully:

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
    var offTopic = bot.channels.get("448400100591403024");
    console.log(offTopic);
});
```

Of course, there are a huge range of event listeners available, which will suit the scenario in which you want to find the channel. You'll find event listeners in the [Events section of the Client Class in the DiscordJS docs.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)
Try this out, and let me know if it works.

**Update: 2022**

In discord.js v12 and above, `bot.channels.get();` should now be `bot.channels.cache.get();`

Comment: You should use `.get` here instead.

Comment: I am using the exact same code but I'm getting the error "bot.channels.get is not a function"

Answer (score 20):

It seems like the new version of the library uses [`.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) instead of `.get` and it returns a promise:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.channels.fetch('448400100591403024')
    .then(channel => console.log(channel.name));
});
```

Comment: Note : this anwser solve the main issue. My code still have another minor issue, which was to start fetching channels outside of `client.on('ready', ...)`

Answer (score 1):

The way you retrieve information from client changed in discordjs v12, that applies if the information was cached tho.

```
var offTopic = bot.channels.cache.get('448400100591403024'); //.get('448392061415325697');
console.log(offTopic);
```

If the information isn't cached, you will need to use the fetch method that Taylan suggested. This method uses Discord API to get the Discord object by an ID.

```
client.channels.fetch('448400100591403024')
  .then(channel => console.log(channel.name));
```

You can read more about changes brought with discordjs v12 [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#commonly-used-methods-that-changed)

Answer (score 0):

```
    bot.on('ready', (message) => {
        var offTopic = client.channels.cache.get("448400100591403024")
        console.log(offTopic)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either via .then promise call or via async await as explained here: .

Code will be like this (change the variable `client` to your bot if needed):

```
let channel = await client.channels.fetch('channel-id-here')

// or you can use:

client.channels.fetch('channel-id-here').then( () => {
  // do something here
})
```

I hope it helps both sort of scenarios.