# Why does this not send embed to channel id? discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've tried multiple ways to try to get it to send but it shows no error and doesn't send into channel.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');



client.on("ready", async () => {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Bot Status!`)
      .setDescription(`${client.user.username} **Is Online!**`)
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1006667208371490946')
    channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in the latest Discord.js version (V14) the correct way is

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

client.on("ready", async () => {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(`Bot Status!`)
      .setDescription(`${client.user.username} **Is Online!**`);
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1006667208371490946')
    channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
});
```

If this is not solving your issue,
try to add a console.log(channel) just before `channel.send({embeds: [embed]})`

If the result is `undefined`, the problem is the bot can't get in your cache the channel you want. In that case you can fetch ([Link to a post speaking about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463163/discord-bot-cant-find-channel-by-name-or-id))
In the other case the bot can't send a message in the channel, could be a permission issue but you can add a .then() / .catch() to see if error is showed or not.

Hope this can helps you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't have the `client` to call.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

client.on("ready", async (/*client not found in here*/) => {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Bot Status!`)
      .setDescription(`${client.user.username} **Is Online!**`)
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1006667208371490946')
    channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
})
```

So try to add `client`

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

client.on("ready", async(client) => {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Bot Status!`)
      .setDescription(`${client.user.username} **Is Online!**`)
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1006667208371490946')
    channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
})
```