# Can't get channel object by ID with Discord Bot. "TypeError: bot.channels.get is not a function"

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I'm working on a simple discord bot that will choose a random message from a specific channel in my discord server. But I get an error when I try to get the channel object using the get method.

I'm fairly new to Javascript so I've been trying to follow similar examples online. Here's what I have:

```
switch(cmd) {
    case 'squadname':
        var squadNameChannel = bot.channels.get('the_channel_id');
        var namesArr = squadNameChannel.messages;
        var squadName = namesArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * namesArr.length)].content;
        bot.sendMessage({
            to: channelID,
            message: squadName
        });
        break;
}
```

When I enter the command in the text channel I get this error in the command prompt: "TypeError: bot.channels.get is not a function"

The main example I was following was from here: [Discord Bot Can't Get Channel by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515134/discord-bot-cant-get-channel-by-name)

To preempt some answers:

- Yes, my client is also called 'bot'
- In my actual code 'the_channel_id' is replaced with the actual channel ID
- I also tried using the 'find' method with the channel name and got an error that said that 'find' is not a function