# Discord.py how to get a server's id?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to set up unban but I'm not sure how to get a server's id to make it work. How would I go about getting the server's id?

Comment: Depends on if you're trying to get it from an event or a command and if you're trying to get it from a name or just a list of servers your bot is connected to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to enable `Developer Mode` in your discord client, and copy the ID from there.  [Follow the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515134/discord-bot-cant-get-channel-by-name/41515544#41515544), then right click on the server icon and choose `Copy ID` from the context menu.

If your bot is receiving commands, then you can resolve the server the command is from through the message that invoked the command.  For example:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=true)
async def unban(ctx, user: discord.User):
    await bot.unban(ctx.message.server, user)
```

This doesn't do any validations such as permission checking, checking the bot has permissions, or checking that the `user` is actually banned, but it should be enough to get the idea.