# How to make so that the creator of the server chose where bot messages that the new user has joined the server will be sent?

Tags: python, postgresql, discord, bots, discord.py

I have this code:

```
class member_greeting(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self, ctx):
    pass

@commands.command()
async def greet(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    guild_channel_id = ctx.message.guild.id
    cursor.execute(f'UPDATE public."prefixDB" SET channel_for_greet=\'{channel}\' WHERE guild_id = \'{guild_channel_id}\';')
    conn.commit()
    
@commands.command()
async def print(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    guild_channel_id = ctx.message.guild.id
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT channel_for_greet FROM public."prefixDB" WHERE guild_id = \'{guild_channel_id}\';')
    channel = cursor.fetchone()
    
    await channel[0].send('ok')
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(member_greeting(bot))
```

The greet command enters the name of the channel into the database (if instead of the link to the channel you write id, the name will still be entered, this is because of discord.TextChannel)

The print command should take the name of the channel from the database and send a message there, but it was not there if you write simply

```
await channel.send ( 'ok')
```

then in the console, it shows that the tuple does not have the send attribute, and if the first element is selected from the cortege

```
await channel [0].send('ok')
```

who reports that str has no send attribute.

What should be done in my case?

Perhaps you should use some other PostgreSQL command?

[image: in pgAdmin 4]

Comment: You only fetch the channel name, not the bot or class that will send the message. I recommend that you a look at the overall structure of your code to understand what information is sent and stored where, because it looks like you got lost somewhere along the way. That's fine of course, it happens to all of us, but it's good to take a step back and reflect on what you're doing

Comment: But how to get the name of the channel or hell, so that later it can be used to send a message?

Comment: `channel[0]` *is* the name of the channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only fetch the channel name, so you need to use the client (is that the bot?) to send the message for you, see [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel):

```py
channel = client.get_channel(12324234183172)
await channel.send('hello')
```

Here, the channel is not the name, but the ID. If possible, I would store the ID of the channel in the database instead of the name, because names are very prone to change. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515544/5015356) describes how to get the channel name by the ID, but it's literally a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I reviewed my code, found errors, and corrected them.
Here is the correct code:

```
class member_greeting(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, ctx):
    join_guild_id = ctx.guild.id

    cursor.execute(f'SELECT channel_for_greeting FROM public."prefixDB" WHERE guild_id = \'{join_guild_id}\';')
    chan = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(chan[0]) #the motorcade returns to us therefore it is necessary to choose a position
    
    await channel.send('hi')

@commands.command()
async def greet(self, ctx, channel):
    guildid = ctx.guild.id
    cursor.execute(f'UPDATE public."prefixDB" SET channel_for_greeting = \'{channel}\' WHERE guild_id = \'{guildid}\';')
    conn.commit()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(member_greeting(bot))
```